# How to update components created inside a JSX.Element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-component

I have a root component as:

```
const EnterMobileNumberPage: React.FC = () => {

    return (
        <div 
            className="Page" 
            id="enterMobileNumberPage"
        >
            <CardView>
                <p 
                    className="TitleLabel" 
                >
                    Please enter your mobile number
                </p>
                <input 
                    className="PlainInput" 
                    type="text" 
                    maxLength={10}
                    onChange={inputAction}
                />
                <FilledButton 
                    title="Next" 
                    action={buttonAction} 
                    invalid
                />
            </CardView>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Where `CardView` and `FilledButton` are my custom components. `FilledButton` has logic shown below:

```
type FilledButtonProps = {
    title: string,
    bgcolor?: string,
    color?: string,
    invalid?: boolean,
    action?: ()=>void
}

const FilledButton: React.FC<FilledButtonProps> = (props) => {

    const [, updateState] = React.useState();
    const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

    let backgroundColor: string | undefined

    if(props.bgcolor){
        backgroundColor = props.bgcolor
    }

    if(props.invalid === true){
        backgroundColor = "#bcbcbc"
    }

    const overrideStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        color: props.color
    } 

    return (
        <a 
            className="FilledButton" 
            onClick={props.action}
        >
            <div style={overrideStyle}>
                {props.title}
            </div>
        </a>

    );
}
```

Here, I want to listen to text change event in input element. What should I write so that `inputAction` has a way to update `FilledButton`?

For example, I may want to change `FilledButton`'s `invalid` to `false` when input element has 10 digits number.

(I didn't introduce Redux, since I'm quite a beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you want to update the props receibe by `<FilledButton />`, you only need to store a state (call it `action`, maybe) when your `inputAction` onChange function is trigger, that way you'll update that state and that state is been pass to you children component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const EnterMobileNumberPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [action, setAction] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = e => {
      if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
        setAction(e.target.value);
      }
    };

    return (
        <div 
            className="Page" 
            id="enterMobileNumberPage"
        >
            <CardView>
                <p className="TitleLabel" >
                    Please enter your mobile number
                </p>
                <input 
                    className="PlainInput" 
                    type="text" 
                    maxLength={10}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <FilledButton 
                    title="Next" 
                    action={buttonAction} 
                    invalid={action.length === 10}
                />
            </CardView>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then, you'll have an `action` estate, that you could use to block your `<FilledButton />`and also to use it as the `<input />` value, Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to update sibling component, the only way you have is to re-render parent component and pass updated prop to sibling component so it will also update.

```
const EnterMobileNumberPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [mobileVal, inputAction] = React.useState('');
    return (
        <div>
            <input 
                className="PlainInput" 
                type="text" 
                maxLength={10}
                onChange={inputAction} // Updating parent component state on change
            />
            <FilledButton 
                title="Next" 
                action={buttonAction} 
                invalid
                mobileLength={mobileVal.length} // New prop for filled button
            />
        </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Having a try now.